# what is the default index value in array?

Tags: java

i came across a code in java that doesn't have a array initialization. when there is an increment in the value,it changes to 1.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int ar1[] = new int[26];
    String first="abc";

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
      ar1[first.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
      System.out.println(ar1[i]);
    }



  }


}
```

the output is 1
1
1. how does that happen

Comment: The default value for `int[]` is `0`. This, `int ar1[] = new int[26];` fills the array with twenty-six zeros.

Comment: It happens because the letters a, b, and c, only appear _once_ in your input string.  Take a string that has `a` appearing more than once, and your code should correctly record the count.

Answer (score 1):

The default value is **zero**.

`ar1[first.charAt(i) - 'a']++;` increments the value which corresponds to the particular letter. What it basically does is count the frequency of letters in a string.

in `abc`,  a is ar[0], b is ar1[1], and so on